# Programming routing protocol for MANet in Java(UDP)

Tags: java, mobile, udp, protocols, distributed

I'm programming mobile ad hoc network routing protocol in JAVA (using UDP). That routing protocol consists of ring topology (each node as one predecessor node and one successor node).
First, I've combined one transmitter (one thread) and one receiver (one thread) to form one node. But, I'm facing some problems like:

1. I'd that a third node could listen transmission from one node to another node. Per example,
   node A sends a packet to node B, and if node C is in the range of node A then it might listen that transmission too.
2. I'd set one channel per ring to reduce interference. But, I don't know which java network API mechanism I should use.

   I'd have your guidance.
   Thank you in advance (sorry for my poor english)!

Comment: 1. sounds like a typical usecase for asynchronous encryption. maybe start at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)

Answer (score 0):

```
Per example, node A sends a packet to node B, and if node C is in the range of node A then it might listen that transmission too.
```

This is expected behavior for wireless ad-hoc network. If C is not destination (according to MAC-address) you can drop received message.

> I'd set one channel per ring to reduce interference.

One channel per ring would oppositely increase interference, especially if you expect high load and many messages being routed around. But it is much easier to manage single channel.

You need to think more what is your environment and requirements.

- Are you using 802.11 at MAC level?
- Do you want reliable guaranteed delivery?

Comment: Oh, you're right. I'm not going to use one channel per ring. But, also, I cannot use just one channel for entire protocol. That protocol will be ring of rings.
I don't know how to use 802.11 at MAC level. I'm developing a simple application to "proof the concept" at application layer. And, nothing about guaranteed delivery. Thank you for your help!